# Setting custom field values on a card with the Trello API

Tags: api, object, trello, trello-powerup

I am trying to use the new Custom Fields methods of the [Trello API](https://developers.trello.com/v1.0/reference#custom-fields) to set the value of a custom field on a card.

I've created a custom field of type `number`. When I make a `GET` request for the custom field by it's `id`, it returns this custom field object:

```
{
"id":"5ab13cdb8acaabe576xxxxx",
"idModel":"54ccee71855b401132xxxxx",
"modelType":"board",
"fieldGroup":"837a643fd25acc835affc227xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"name":"Test Number Field",
"pos":16384,
"type":"number"
}
```

Then when I create a new card in the Trello UI (but do not type in a value in the `Test Number Field` box) and then `GET` that card using the `customFieldItems=true` (as documented [here](https://developers.trello.com/v1.0/docs/getting-started-custom-fields#section-get-customfielditem-for-single-card)), it returns this card object (irrelevant fields removed):

```
{
"id": "5ab56e6b62abac194d9xxxxx",
"name": "test1",
"customFieldItems": []
}
```

Note that since I did not type anything into the `Test Number Field` box in the UI, the `customFieldItems` property contains an empty array.

Then if I type in the number `1` in the `Test Number Field` box in the UI and `GET` the card again, it returns this (irrelevant fields removed):

```
{
"id": "5ab56e6b62abac194d9xxxxx",
"name": "test1",
"customFieldItems":
    [
        {
        "id": "5ab570c5b43ed17b2dxxxxx",
        "value": {
            "number": "1"
            },
        "idCustomField": "5ab13cdb8acaabe5764xxxxx",
        "idModel": "5ab56e6b62abac194d9xxxxx",
        "modelType": "card"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to set the value of this custom field via API.

When I go to the API documentation for *"Setting, updating, and removing the value for a Custom Field on a card,"* ([here](https://developers.trello.com/v1.0/reference#customfielditemsid)) I plug in the following information:

#### Query Auth

- `key`: *(our valid/working Trello API key)*
- `token`: *(our valid/working Trello API token)*

#### PATH PARAMS

- `idCard`: *(ID of the card that the Custom Field value should be set/updated for)* `5ab56e6b62abac194d9xxxxx`
- `idCustomField` *(ID of the Custom Field on the card.)*: `5ab570c5b43ed17b2dxxxxx`

#### QUERY PARAMS

- `idCustomField` (ID of the Custom Field to which the item belongs.): `5ab13cdb8acaabe576xxxxx`
- `modelType` *(This should always be card.)*: `card`
- `value` *(An object containing the key and value to set for the card's Custom Field value. The key used to set the value should match the type of Custom Field defined.)*: `{"number": 2}`

When I click Try It, I get the response: `400 Bad Request "Invalid custom field item value."`

I've tried the following things:

- Switching the two `idCustomField` values (it's confusing that both the path parameter and query parameter have the same name, implying that they are meant to accept the same value, but then they have different descriptions, and the descriptions are vague/confusing).
- Setting both `idCustomField` values to the same thing (for both of the possible IDs)
- Setting the value to `2`, `{"number": "2"}`, `{number: 2}`, `{number: "2"}` and more.

No matter what I try, I always get `"Invalid custom field item value."` This behaves the same way whether the card has a value in the custom field or not.

I'm pretty sure that the `idCustomField` in the path params is being accepted, because when I change one character, it gives me this error instead: `"invalid value for idCustomField"`.

So I don't know if the `"Invalid custom field item value."` is referring to the query param `idCustomField*` or the `value`.

I also don't know if it makes a difference whether or not the card has an existing value in the custom field, but I want to be able to set the value of this custom field regardless of whether or not it currently has a value in the field.

Comment: I believe this is the problem with `value` since when I tried `https://api.trello.com/1/card/.../customField/.../item?value=&key=...&token=...`, it cleared the value successfully. Maybe we should encode or stringify the value object different way from the doc says. I will try other methods and let you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The live example (using `XMLHttpRequest`) on [the Trello documentation page](https://developers.trello.com/v1.0/reference#setting-custom-field-values-on-cards) is wrong. You should use the next example using `fetch`.

```
var url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{idCard}/customField/{idCustomField}/item?token={yourToken}&key={yourKey}";
var data = {value: { number: "42" }};
fetch(url, { body: JSON.stringify(data), method: 'PUT', headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}})
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then((data) => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)))
.catch((err) => console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)))
```

This example works. And after trying this, I modified the `XMLHttpRequest` version and it worked too.

```
var data = null;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

data = {value: { number: "3" }};  //added
var json = JSON.stringify(data);  //added

xhr.open("PUT", 'https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{idCard}/customField/{idCustomField}/item?key={yourkey}&token={yourtoken}');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json');  //added
xhr.send(json);  //modified
```

The point is that you should 1) set the request `Content-type` header to `application/json` and 2) pass the `value` via JSON object body.

I tried to edit the live example on the documentation but I it was not possible. I hope they will fix it soon.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Also, it looks like Trello just updated their documentation page to remove the extraneous query params `idCustomField` and `modelType`, and they also added a note to always send strings as values (like for boolean and number values).

Comment: @Employee: "always send strings as values (like for boolean and number values)" saved me. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: can this code be simplified to the url called? i'm having the same problem in R but can't translate it